# Awk printf() overwrites print()

Tags: bash, awk

I need to output the information of the CPUs, based on the `/proc/cpuinfo` in folowing format:

```
Number  model name  cache size
1       AMD Turion  512 KB
2       Intel       1024 KB
 ...
```

For doing this I used folowing bash script:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep -e "cache size" -e "model name" |awk -f Awk
```

The code of file **Awk** is:

```
function getProcNumber(i){
  return (i-1)/2 + 1
}

BEGIN { 
  print("Number\tmodel name\tcache size")
  i = 1
}
{
  if(i%2 == 1){
    printf(getProcNumber(i), " ", $4, " " $5, " ", $6, "\t")
  }
  else{
    print($4, " ", $5)
  }
  i++
}
```

I know, that `print()` appends new line character to the line by default. So I decided to use `printf()`. 
But the output of the `printf()` **was owerwrote by** `print()` in `else` branch and I got such result:

```
Number  model name  cache size
1512   KB
2512   KB
```

If I use `print()` instead of `printf()`, I got an output, which was nearest to the correct format:
Number  model name  cache size

```
1   AMD  Turion(tm)   II    
512   KB
2   AMD  Turion(tm)   II    
512   KB
```

But, as you can see, there are new line characters after word **II**.
**How should I change my code to get required format of the output?**

Comment: What is the rule for the transformation of the model name? Up to the first opening parenthesis?

Comment: No. As you can see from the code, I simply take 3 first words from the model name.

Comment: I can see that you do that in your code, but it doesn't seem to match your desired output at the top of the question.

Comment: Yes, I need to output all model name, starting with $4 (i.e. $4, $5, ... end_of_line), but it is an oprional demand

Comment: Any reason not to refactor everything into the Awk script? While the `cat` is definitely [useless](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) I can imagine situations where maybe you'd keep the regexes separate from the formatting script; but I am suspicious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first expression in a `printf` statement must be a format. (This is the same as the C `printf` function.) A format is a string including conversion specifiers, each of which corresponds to a following argument. The specifiers have the form `%<optional modifiers><type>`, where `<type>` is a single character indicating the type of conversion: `s` (string), `d` (decimal), `f` (fixed point), `x` (hexadecimal), etc.

If the format string has no specifiers, then it just gets printed *and all the following arguments to printf are ignored*. In your case, the first argument to printf is an integer, which certainly will not have any `%` in it. So it's not a question of the other arguments being overwritten. They are never printed in the first place.

Probably what you wanted is something like this:

```
printf("%d %s %s %s\t", getProcNumber(i), $4, $5, $6)
```

You might want to read the [section about printf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-printf-statement-1) in the gawk user's guide.

---

By the way, in `awk` the variable `NR` is always the current line number, so there is no need to count lines yourself.

Comment: Thanks very much! And how should I change this string to output not only $4, $5, $6 but all string ($0), starting with $4?

Comment: As for $NR... If I use it instead of getProcNumber(i), I always get number 0.

Comment: Call awk with `-F '\t: '` or set `FS = "\t: "` in the `BEGIN` block and use `$2` (`\t: ` separates the property names from their values in `/proc/cpuinfo`). And use `NR`, not `$NR` -- `$NR` is the value of the last field in a line.

Comment: @VeLKerr: You could print them one at a time, with a for loop. For example: `for (i=4;i<=NF;++i) printf " %s", $i; printf "\t";

Comment: @VeLKerr: awk is not bash. In awk, `$` is an operator with an integer argument, whose value is the indicated field from the current input. It's worth reading the Gawk user manual; it's a nice introduction to programming in Awk. When I said "use the variable NR", I meant "use the variable NR".

Comment: Those lines come from `/proc/cpuinfo` and are delimited by a tab followed by a colon followed by a space. An easy way to extract the property value from such a line is to split it with `\t: ` as a field separator and take the second field (which is also the last).

Comment: @rici: when I use `NR` (without `$`), I get only odd numbers (1, 3, ...) because CPU model and cache size are in different lines of the `/proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: @VeLKerr: Yes, it will be exactly like your variable `i`. You would have to use `getProcNumber(NR)`.